# Excel VBA - code to right click on specific area of screen

Tags: excel, vba

Hi and thanks in advance, I couldn't find what I wanted in an existing question so here goes!

I have a VBA macro which is going into a different application to carry out a task and I need the macro to right click on a certain part of the other application in order to select one of the options from the right click menu.

The macro curently activates the different application but I cannot figure out how to simulate a right click.

Any help would be appreciated. My current code is below up to the point where I would like to put the right click code.

```
Set DataSheet = Workbooks("Deactivate Lines v 1 Jan 2020.xlsm").Sheets("Deactivation")

Dim ItemCode As String
Dim Status As String

ItemCode = ActiveCell.Value
Status = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

AppActivate "Boots - KiSoft NAVIGATOR"
Sleep 350
Application.SendKeys "{F3}", True
Sleep 1000
Application.SendKeys "{tab 2}", True
Sleep 350
Application.SendKeys (ItemCode), True
Sleep 350
Application.SendKeys ("~"), True
Sleep 350

'this is where I would like to put the right click code
```

Comment: the option is only available on the right-click menu? Are you sure it isnt anywhere else?

Comment: Yes positive. It is a warehouse management system where there are no shortcuts or buttons with the same function.

Comment: It looks like you either have to do an API or this.. Application.SendKeys ("+{F10}")